# Android include audio files with app package

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, audio-player, android-music-player

I need to build a standalone audio/music player that should be able to play different audio files in 2 languages, english and russian as they are selected.

I thought that would be and easy task since I found a lot of examples for a player that read from an SDCARD.

The problem is that in this specific case I want to bring the audio files within the app and read them from a specific folder inside the project (ex. /audio/eng/ or /audio/rus/). Is there a way to collect the audio files from one of these folders that come along with the app and play them?

I have very small experience in android applications but I wish to solve the problem.

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: Use the `assets` folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a file to an Android project, deploy it to the device, and then open it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663847/how-to-add-a-file-to-an-android-project-deploy-it-to-the-device-and-then-open)

Comment: Thank you for your advice Simon, but I'm wondering about a topic I've read about the assets. Is it true the limit of 1MB for single file? I mean, since this apk will be installed without using the Play Store, the audio files inside are all of about 5MB size each one. Is it true the limit? This app should resemble more like an audio guide.